# How do i find out what pulseaudio module does what?

Tags: command-line, drivers, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm new to Linux (just installed Ubuntu for the first time yesterday) and Ubuntu keeps setting my default audio device as the inbuilt speakers on my laptop so i want to remove the module for them so it will default to the wireless headset that I have connected to it, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Sorry but wrong approach. Don't mess with modules.  Start by installing pavucontrol and see if the settings there help.

Comment: ok thank you Rinzwind, i will try that to see if it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All modules loaded in a default Ubuntu installation do make sense and there should not be any need to remove them. Having said that it is of course near impossible to be ready for all special requirements we may have. Defaults are just what most people need. Before we adapt our defaults we need some basic understanding what a given module will do, and how we are able to restore our default settings in case anything went wrong.

#### How do I load a module?

Here is an official list of all supported modules:

- [Pulseaudio Modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/)

All modules can be loaded or unloaded for testing to a running pulseaudio sound server with the following commands in a terminal:

```
pactl load-module <name> <settings>
pactl unload-module <name|index>
```

For example we can load a module that will switch audio output to a newly connected headset by this:

```
pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

In case we are happy we can add this module to our `default.pa` file to load it everytime the sound server restarts.

#### How do I reset to default?

Any modules loaded at runtime with `pactl` can also be unloaded by restarting the pulseaudio sound server. This will load all modules defined in the `default.pa` file. This is done with

```
pulseaudio -k
```

We may not want to use the system-wide defaults from `/etc/pulse/default.pa` but use our own setting valid only for one user instead. We can store this in our home directory in `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`. On boot or on restarting pulseaudio settings there will override the system-wide settings.

To make our own `default.pa` file there just start with

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

We can then easily edit this file with any editor.

In case anything goes wrong we just delete the `~/.config/pulse` directory, and restart pulseaudio to load the previous system-wide defaults (and re-create a vanilla `~/.config/pulse`).

Comment: I finally got the command to work! I thought the whole time that at the end of pactl was a 1. so after I ran that command it came up with the number 40, now what?

Comment: @Sol33t303: the number you get is the index number a module was registered (also see `pactl list short modules` for all active modules).